# add a prefix to each line of the log with the application name

Tags: scala, log4j

This could be a very silly question but I cannot find the way to achieve it.

I would like to add a prefix to each log line with the application name.

Eg: current log

```
15/11/09 10:37:06 INFO - BlaBla
```

Log To Be:

```
15/11/09 10:37:06 MYAPPLICATION: INFO - BlaBla
```

Is it possible to configure log4j.properties to obtain so?

I saw [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459089/is-it-possible-to-prefix-every-line-of-a-stacktrace-in-log4j) but I have problems in translating it to Scala and I am not even sure that it is the right way to do so

Comment: Is this application name static, i.e. known at build time, or does it somehow change during the runtime?

Comment: Known at build time.

Comment: Then why don't you just modify the `appender`s pattern to include the app name as a constant string there?

Comment: because I did not think of that. I feel very stupid right now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Haspemulator it is sufficient to do

```
appenderName = appName restOfThePattern
```